# What is out_height in the tensorflow.nn.conv2d docstring?

Tags: tensorflow, convolution

I ask this here, because the Tensorflow repo now states that the issues there are only for feature requests and bugs.

In the `tf.nn.conv2d` docstring, it states, as the second thing this method does is:

```
Extracts image patches from the input tensor to form a *virtual*
tensor of shape `[batch, out_height, out_width,
filter_height * filter_width * in_channels]`.
```

**What is the `out_height` and the `out_width` in the docstring above?**

I imagine this the number is determined by the input and filter dimensions, but I wish this wasn't implied and was more explicit, or there was an example.

Comment: This should help you understand the `stride` argument: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34642595/tensorflow-strides-argument

Comment: Is the out_height what the stride is? If out_height is the stride, that's news to me, but I don't think it is.  Thank you for sharing that answer, but it did not enlighten me.  Is out_height the size of the stride kernel?

Comment: out_height is a function of the height of your input images. E.g. with padding='SAME" and stride=1, a batch of 10 32x32 RGB images with give an out_height of 32. use stride=2, and out_height will be 16. Etc.